# How to place text between elements only when those elements are present?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I only code at a very amateur level and I recently undertook a large scale project with XML files. Basically I need to take these XML files and display them in a nicely formatted, readable way. I would like to write one XSLT file for all the XML files I have.

Each XML file hase several elements with the same name `<datafield tag="650">`.
Nested in these elements are several other elements. There will always be a `<subfield code="a">`. There may be no other subfields after that, or there may be `<subfield code="x">`, `<subfield code="z">`, or `<subfield code"v">` in any combination. I would like to put hyphens between the subfields, but only when these subfields are visible.

For example I have tried this:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="so01.xsl"?>

<record>
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="0">
        <subfield code="a">Anthropology</subfield>
        <subfield code="z">Southwest, New</subfield>
        <subfield code="v">Periodicals.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="0">
        <subfield code="a">Indians of North America</subfield>
        <subfield code="z">Southwest, New</subfield>
        <subfield code="v">Periodicals.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="0">
        <subfield code="a">Archaeology</subfield>
        <subfield code="v">Periodicals.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="7">
        <subfield code="a">Anthropology.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="7">
        <subfield code="a">Antiquities.</subfield>
        <subfield code="x">History.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="7">
        <subfield code="a">Archaeology.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="7">
        <subfield code="a">Indians of North America.</subfield>
    </datafield>
</record>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <body>
            <p>
                <xsl:for-each select="record/datafield[@tag='650']">&#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160;
                    <xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='a']"/>--<xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='x']"/>--<xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='z']"/>--<xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='v']"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </p>
        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This sort of works, but it places hyphens even when the subfields aren’t present, which would be confusing for the reader.

Thanks for any help on this, I greatly appreciate it. I'm also done with the code and this may be (fingers crossed) the last step. Then I just need to batch edit the XML files to attach to the XSL file.

Comment: This is quite a broad question, complicated by the fact that you are treating XSLT as an imperative language.  XSLT has constructs that look imperative (i.e. a stylesheet is seen as a program that makes things happen), but at the core it is not.  The _input XML_ is driving the process, and at each new input element the stylesheet is consulted to figure out what to do.  Evan Lenz's [How XSLT works](http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/) is an excellent introduction to the functional (push) nature of XSL.

Comment: ... Anything other than a toy stylesheet will use both, but thinking primarily in functional (push) mode will save you a lot of trouble as your system gets larger.

Answer (score 1):

*This sort of works, but it places hyphens even when the `<subfield>` aren’t present* - There is no condition to check whether `<subfield>` element having a particular value in the `@code` attribute is present in the input XML or not. An `<xsl:if test="">` condition before every `<xsl:value-of>` would have handled this case.

However there are different ways to write XSLT code to generate the required HTML output. The current XSLT code will produce a single `<p>` tag having all the values from the `<subfield>` elements which I believe is not what is required. I think you would need a separate `<p>` tag corresponding to every `<datafield @tag='650'>` and having a `hyphen` separated value for the `<subfield>` child elements.

In order to achieve this output, the template would need to changed as below.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="record/datafield[@tag='650']">
                <!-- create <p> tag for every <datafield> -->
                <p>
                    <!-- instead of hardcoding <subfield> elements, loop through
                         the available <subfield> element having @code attribute -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="subfield[@code]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        <!-- if the position of the <subfield> is not last 
                             append hyphen characters to concatenated string -->
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                            <xsl:text>--</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

This generates an HTML as below

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Anthropology--Southwest, New--Periodicals.</p>
        <p>Indians of North America--Southwest, New--Periodicals.</p>
        <p>Archaeology--Periodicals.</p>
        <p>Anthropology.</p>
        <p>Antiquities.--History.</p>
        <p>Archaeology.</p>
        <p>Indians of North America.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above XSLT code is just one way to achieve the output. The same XSLT can be re-written / modified using different matching templates instead of nested `<xsl:for-each>` or templates handling specific values of `@code` i.e. if only `@code = 'a' or 'v' or 'x' or 'z'` are to be considered and any other value to be ignored.